# How to write a class that can be used on the left hand side of an in statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class called Mode that contains an augmented variable; a single variable which can be accessed as an integer (0 to 6) or one of 7 predefined strings.

I want to write a statement of the form:

```
specials = {'SW_SET_HW_RST': SwSetHwRst,
            'HW_SET_SW_RST': HwSetSwRst}
if mode in specials:
   specials[mode].code(f, setting)
```

where mode is an instantiation of my class. For some reason that I do not understand, I get the error message:
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'Mode'

I cannot use the **hash** method as that returns an integer.  Can anyone give me some clue as to how to return the string version of the mode when used on the left hand side of an in and in a dictionary lookup as above?

Full code of the mode class is shown below:

```
class Mode():
    ''' class to flexibly handle the access mode of a setting within a register
        Whereas mode used to be int, which does not make the code very readable
        MODE can now be accessed as an int or as a string, allowing self documenting code
    '''
    MODES = {0: 'RW',
             1: 'R',
             2: 'CONST',
             3: 'SW_SET_HW_RST',
             4: 'SW_SET_HW_UPD',
             5: 'HW_SET_SW_RST',
             6: 'W',
             7: 'VRW'
            }

    MODE_INV = {v:k for k,v in MODES.items()}


    def __init__(self, mode):
        ''' instantiation can take a legacy numeric key or a string key
        '''
        if mode not in self.MODES.keys() and mode not in self.MODE_INV.keys():
            raise ValueError('Undefined register mode: %s' % (mode))
        if mode in self.MODES.keys():
            self._mode = mode
        else:
            self._mode = self.MODE_INV[mode]


    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._mode == other if isinstance(other, int) else self.MODES[self._mode] == other


    def __str__(self):
        return self.MODES[self._mode]


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.MODES[self._mode]

    @property
    def is_read_only(self):
        return self._mode in [1, 4, 5]

    @property
    def is_rw(self):
        return self._mode in [0, 3, 7]

    @property
    def is_writable(self):
        return self._mode not in [1, 2]

    @property
    def legacy(self):
        ''' for legacy use
        '''
        return self._mode
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your Mode class?

Comment: maybe you need to do specials[mode]().code(f, setting) ?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't reproduce the error mentionned. Please post a proper minimal **reproducible** example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Full code of the class is added to my original question.

Comment: I wrote my own test case and it seems my assumption was incorrect.  Mode works correctly if it it is used with a list but not if it is used with a dictionary.  I guess that is where the error comes from.

Comment: I have solved it.  I just needed to add a correct __hash__ method.  The method is:     def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.MODES[self._mode])

Comment: Can this question be reopened so that I may answer it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You should not get the hash error from the code in the question. This error comes about when Python tries to hash an object to use as a **key** in a `dict`, the class of which do not implement `__has__`. In your code, all the keys are `str`s and so everything is OK.

Do you actually attempt to store any instances of `Mode` (e.g. `SwSetHwRst` or `HwSetSwRst`, I suppose) as keys in `specials`? Note also that even if you never attempt to *store* such invalid keys, just the act of *looking up* an invalid key results in the same error. I.e. `SwSetHwRst in specials` is illegal, assuming `SwSetHwRst` to be of type `Mode`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found if I force Python to use the string version of the object by using str(mode) then everything works just fine.